# Obtaining scope variable from separate HTML file

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular template that pulls in two HTML pages ...

1. sidebar.html
2. content.html

   In content.html I use a controller to make an API call that gives a true/false response and based on that response I render different text. Is there a way that I can gain access to the same true/false response from within sidebar.html? I would rather not duplicate the API call done in the controller for content.html.

**content.html**

```
<div data-ng-controller="AuthorizeController">

    <div ng-if="isUserAuthorized">
        text if User is authorized ...
    </div>

    <div ng-if="!isUserAuthorized">
        text if User is NOT authorized ...
    </div>

</div>
```

**AuthorizeController.js**

```
(function () {

    var dependencies = [
        '$scope',
        AuthorizeController
    ];

    module.controller('AuthorizeController', dependencies);

    function AuthorizeController($scope) {
      // Code to determine if authorized omitted for brevity
      if (true) {
        $scope.isUserAuthorized = true;
      } else {
        $scope.isUserAuthorized = false;
      }
    }

})();
```

I should add that the portion of the controller that is determining if the user is authenticated does so via an API call. I am hoping to make the API call only once.

Comment: sounds like a good case for angular `service`

Comment: @JossefHarush is definitely right =)

Comment: If I encapsulated the call in a service how would I go about accessing the result in both HTML pages? Without repeating the service call?

Comment: as mentioned you can write a service, or broadcast the value but this leads to tight coupling, a service is a better solution.

Comment: @JossefHarush is right. This definitely should go in a service, then use DI to inject the same service into different controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an angular `service` ([?](http://blog.pluralsight.com/angularjs-step-by-step-services)) to share the authentication logic between your controllers.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/n3iOSkAefxy8xRW7vzFG?p=preview

**javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope, authenticationService) {
    $scope.isAuthenticated = authenticationService.isAuthenticated();
  }
);

app.controller('sidebarCtrl',function($scope, authenticationService) {
    $scope.isAuthenticated = authenticationService.isAuthenticated();
  }
);

app.factory('authenticationService',function() {

    return {
      isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated
    }

    function isAuthenticated(){
      // Place your logic here
      return true;
    }

  }
);
```

**html**

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div>
      <h1>Obtaining scope variable from separate HTML file</h1>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    {{ isAuthenticated }}
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="sidebarCtrl">
    {{ isAuthenticated }}
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: If the API called was re-factored into a service wouldn't the service still need to be executed twice? One for each controller that makes use of it (mainCtrl and sidebarCtrl)?

Comment: @webworm the service instance is single and shared with your controllers. so you probably need to call the authentication logic once and then you could cache and reuse it the next time another controller needs it

Answer (score 1):

There are three options:

**1st solution:**

Move the logic of Auth to a service, and use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to inject the service into AuthorizeController and SidebarController.

**2nd solution:**

Use [$broadcast/$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) from AuthorizeController and $on on the SidebarController. Although this is not a good solution because then you will have two controllers tightly coupled.

**3rd solution: (Even better than the 1st)**

Write the sidebar as a directive and inject the Auth Service to that.